# Mimicking bash wc functionalities using python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash

I have written a very simple python programme, called wc.py, which mimics "bash wc" behaviour to count the number of words, lines and bytes in a file. My programme is as follow:

```
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
w = 0
l = 0
b = 0


for currentLine in file:
  wordsInLine = currentLine.strip().split(' ')
  wordsInLine = [word for word in wordsInLine if word != '']
  w += len(wordsInLine)
  b += len(currentLine.encode('utf-8'))
  l += 1

#output
print(str(l) + ' ' + str(w) + ' ' + str(b))
```

In order to execute my programme you should execute the following command:

```
python3 wc.py [a file to read the data from]
```

As the result it shows

```
[The number of lines in the file] [The number of words in the file] [The number of bytes in the file] [the file directory path]
```

The files I used to test my code is as follow:

file.txt which contains the following data:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Executing "wc file.txt" returns
`4 4 8`

Executing "python3 wc.py file.txt" returns `4 4 8`

---

Download "Annual enterprise survey: 2020 financial year (provisional) – CSV" from [CSV file download](https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/)

Executing "wc [fileName].csv" returns
`37081 500273 5881081`

Executing "python3 wc.py [fileName].csv" returns
`37081 500273 5844000`

---

and a [something].pdf file

Executing "wc [something].pdf" works.

Executing "python3 code.py" throws the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 10, in <module>
    for currentLine in file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 10: invalid start byte
```

As you can see, the output of `python3 code.py [something].pdf` and `python3 code.py [something].csv` is not the same as what `wc` returns. Could you help me to find the reason of this erroneous behaviour in my code?

Comment: A PDF is not a text file, so you shouldn't expect to be able to read it as one.

Comment: Most Unix text utilities don't try to parse the file as UTF-8. But Python does.

Comment: But wc command works for a PDF file. I want to have the same behaviour in my code.@Barmar

Comment: it treats everything as ASCII, even if it's not really.

Comment: So is there any way to disable the default behaviour of python - treating a text file as ASCII?

Comment: How about the UTF-8 behaviour of python?

Comment: I think you need to read the file in binary mode. You'll have to do your own processing of newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the CSV file, if you look at the difference between your result and that of `wc`:

5881081 - 5844000 = 37081 which is exactly the number of lines.

That is, every line has one additional character in the original file. That character is the carriage return `\r` which got lost in Python because you iterate over lines and don't specify the linebreaks. If you want a byte-correct result, you have to first identify the type of linebreaks used in the file (and watch out for inconsistencies throughout the document).